# spring cloud config-server .properties content-negotiation failing

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

For me the content-negotiation mechanism of the e.g. for .properties is not working in Spring Cloud Config Server after switching to Spring Cloud `Brixton.RC1` or `Brixton.RC2` from `Angel.SR5` and `Angel.SR6`.

The problem occurs when im starting the service using `gradlew bootRun` or `java -jar ...`. It's working in my integration tests though (see *Working Integration-Test* below).

## Usage Scenario:

I want to access the configuration in profile `testing` of application `my-service`, so I'm calling `http://localhost:8888/my-service/testing.properties`.

**Expected result:**

```
some.property=1234
some.other.property=hello there
```

**Actual result:**

Without `Accept`-Header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error 406</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error 406: Not Acceptable</h1>
        <br/>
        Could not find acceptable representation
    </body>
</html>
```

With `Accept`-Header `application/json`:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1461140158009,
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
    "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
    "path": "/config/my-service/default.properties"
}
```

As you tell from the example, the content-negotiation mechanism seems to be working for error-handling but for the configuration access it is not.

## Working Integration-Test:

I wrote the following Spock-Test

```
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=0", "management.port=0"})
@ActiveProfiles("testing")
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = ConfigurationServiceApplication.class)
class ConfigurationAccessTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    TestserverInfo testserverInfo

    def "testing profile returns testing properties"() {
        given:
        RestTemplate rest = new TestRestTemplate(null, null)
        Properties properties = new Properties()

        when:
        String result = rest.getForObject( testserverInfo.getBasePath() + "/my-service-testing.properties", String.class );
        properties.load( new StringReader(result) )

        then:
        properties['test'] == 'Testing Profile World'
        properties['my.long.testing.property'] == 'Testing Profile Property'
    }
```

## Things I already did so far:

1. Wrote a the above Spock-Test for this scenario that **is working** in all noted versions of `Spring Cloud Config Server`
2. Check `ConfigServerMvcConfiguration` for any obvious configuration errors as far as my knowledge of content-negotiation in Spring MVC went
3. Provide a WebMvcConfigurer myself and initializing content-negotiation as in the configuration class referenced above:

   ```
   @EnableWebMvc
   @Configuration
   public class ConfigMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       private final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigMvcConfiguration.class);

       @Override
       public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
           configurer.mediaType("properties", MediaType.valueOf("text/plain"));
           configurer.mediaType("yml", MediaType.valueOf("text/yaml"));
           configurer.mediaType("yaml", MediaType.valueOf("text/yaml"));
           logger.info("media-types added");
       }
   }
   ```

Can anyone reproduce this issue or provide me any guidance on how to resolve it?

Comment: Not sure how that was working before. The url for properties should be http://localhost:8888/my-service-testing.properties Which will be a problem for you because your service has a dash in the name.

Comment: Thank you @spencergibb . I also just realized, I was hunting a ghost.

Comment: can you say what your problem was?

Comment: Sure, sorry to leave that open. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all the ruckus with writing the question I realized: I was hunting a ghost.
While checking the integration-test I wrote myself I found out, that I was trying to access the properties using a wrong url-schema.

#### TLDR

I was trying to access the properties using the URL

```
http://localhost:8888/config/my-service/testing.properties   <-- wrong
rather than
http://localhost:8888/config/my-service-testing.properties   <-- correct
```

#### Details

One can access the properties in JSON format using the following url schema (when not using labels):

```
http://<host>:<port>/<contextPath>/<application>/<profile>
```

If one wants to access the properties in a format other than json, she has to use another url-schema (again example without labels)

```
http://<host>:<port>/<contextPath>/<application>-<profile>.<format>
```

with format beeing properties/yml/yaml as currently supported formats.

Once again a small mistake that can complicate things alot.